# How to pass string with jquery value from model to view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have to capture text box value and display in div which is generated from model.

For example: I need to display "textbox1" value or "textbox2" based on logic. So that I append text from ajax call.

Below one is the c# statement

```
return "Expected value is \"+$('#txtAMC').val();
```

when I am append this value to div as `$('#div1').html(result);` it shown as below

```
Expected value is "+$('#txtAMC').val()
```

But i want result as

> Expected value is textbox value

Can any body help how can i pass text to ajax call. Thanks in advance.

**Javascript**

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/XMLCorrections/XMLCorrections/GetUserInput', 
    type: 'POST', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    success: function (result) { 
        $('#div1').html(result)
});
```

**c#**

```
public string GetUserInput() {
    // some Logic return "Expected value is \"+$('#txtAMC').val(); 
}
```

Comment: can you add more code, what are you using for models, is this for unit testing? what framework are you using.

Comment: i am using c#4.5, mvc 4.                      


jquery Code:                   $.ajax({
                url: '/XMLCorrections/XMLCorrections/GetUserInput',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) { $('#div1').html(result)});
      c#  Code:               public string GetUserInput()
             {// some  Logic   
               return "Expected value is \"+$('#txtAMC').val();
              }

Comment: Don't return javascript back from your controllers. Instead return a serialized json object and do whatever you need to do with it on the success function of the jquery post.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the "data" attribute in the ajax post.
you can do something like -

```
var txtBoxText = $('#txtAMC').val()
var data = {"passedValue":txtBoxText}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Then do whatever you are doing with this value at server and return the value.

Please clarify if I didn't get the question right.

Comment: you are right @stripathi but in my case i am generating `$('#txtAMC').val()` at model only. that code is `xmlCode= Regex.Replace(currentNode.ToString(), "<AMC>(.)*</AMC>", "<AMC>$('#txtAMC').val()</AMC>", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant); ;
htmlCode= "It is an Boeing Account, but model info is not available.  please enter AMC value in below text box or click on cancel for Manual Entry.<br/><br/><b>AMC : </b><input type='text' id='txtAMC' value='" + missingData[0].AMC + "'></input>";`  **this is actual code what i am implementing in logic**

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are getting this as result on callback

```
result = "Expected value is $('#txtAMC').val()";
```

and what you want is

```
result = "Expected value is blah";
```

where `$('#txtAMC').val() === "blah"`

The best option you have is to change the return of `GetUserInput` to the id of the textbox you require like this

```
return "txtAMC";
```

Now on the success callback you can change it to suit your need like this

```
var resultValue = $("#" + result).val();
$('#div1').html("Expected value is " + resultValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to split the function and create an anonymous function then I am iterated that function. Through this logic I achieved output what exactly I want.

```
var splitedData=data.split('+');
var formateText= function(val){ 
  try{
      var fun=new Function('return '+ val); return fun()
     } 
  catch(e){
     return val
     }
}

 var resultedData="";for(var i=0;i<splitedData.length;i++){
       resultedData+=formateText(splitedData[i]);
       }
```

If there is any simple solution then please provide it.